# Tensorflow 2.11.0 Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am tryng to use GPU for tensorflow. I have installed tensorflow by the following command:

```
pip install tensorflow.
```

The code to access gpu on tensorflow is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras import backend as K

def set_gpu_option(which_gpu, fraction_memory):

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = False
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = fraction_memory
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = which_gpu
K.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))
return set_gpu_option('0', 0.9)
```

But I am getting error as follows:

```
2023-10-19 13:10:02.225759: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

On server, I have checked GPU driver is installed as nvidia-smi gives the correct output and cuda-11.2 is installed. Is there anything to install on the GPU server?